# Hibernate 1.0 + JPA + Netbeans 7.01 + Sql server 2005 = Problems to insert into table with GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My environment:

Hibernate 1.0 
JPA
Netbeans 7.01
Sql server 2005

Part of code:

```
public class EdiAgendamentoCliente implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_edi", unique = true, nullable = true)
private Integer idEdi;
```

Error:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading"

---

Im trying to insert values into a table with auto increment, but its not working, can you guys give me some direction here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that was throwing the exception.

Comment: Check the create SQL to make sure that the column is created as ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to nullable false, and check column name in database matches the name attribute

```
@Column(name = "id_edi", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

Comment: then the column on db is not an auto generating id, how was it created did you let hibernate create it ?

Comment: Yes i let hibernate generate the tables but the error persist.